# Folder check in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to check whether a folder exists or not using Javascript?

Thanks,
Karthick

Comment: A folder on the server? On the client? What kind of folder?

Comment: From a staic html and checking a folder in a particular path. (client)

Answer (score 6):

If this is Javascript running within a web browser, you can't.  For (extremely valid) security reasons, Javascript in a web page does not have access to the client filesystem.

If for some reason you wanted to check from a web page whether a folder existed on the server, you could make an Ajax call from Javascript to a server method (e.g. Java, PHP, ASP.NET, etc.) that could (depending on permissions) have access to the server filesystem.

If you are using Javascript as a Windows scripting environment, Microsoft provides a `FileSystemObject` that includes a `FolderExists()` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a folder on your server, you can make an ajax request to it and check the status code:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if (req.readyState < 4) return;

    if (req.status === 200) alert("The folder exists!");
    else alert("The folder does not exist or can not be accessed!");

}

req.open("GET", "/path/to/folder", true);
req.send("");
```

Comment: <script language="JScript">
    <!--
    function checkfolder()
    {
        var myObject;
        myObject = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        if(myObject.FolderExists("c:\\tmp")){
            alert("tmp Folder Exists");
        }  else {
            alert("tmp Folder doesn't exist");
       }
    }
    -->
    </script>

    <form name="myForm">
    <input type="Button" value="Check Folder" onClick='checkfolder()'>
    </form>

Every time i run this i get activex control message? Is there any way to supress it or any other approach to check a file?